# Angular CLI 8 update - URLs not prefixed with base href anymore

Tags: angular, angular-i18n, angular-cli-v8

**Problem**

After updating our Angular application to version 8 (including Angular CLI), URLs are not prefixed with the base href provided in the `angular.json` file anymore, which essentially breaks our application

**Previous, desired behaviour**

When serving the French version of the app locally, opening a web page on `localhost:8000` would redirect me to `localhost:8000/fr`, and every URL I can navigate to from within the app would also be prefixed with `/fr/`.

**New, erroneous behaviour**

When serving the French version of the app locally, opening a web page on `localhost:8000` results in an empty page saying `Cannot GET /`, since the `/fr` is missing. When I open the page at `localhost:8000/fr` right away, I can see the login page, but since our login flow involves a third party, when I come back to our app from said third party I only see a blank page saying `Cannot GET /login` (because the `/fr/` is missing).

**What I have tried thus far (non-exhaustive list, but the two most promising approaches)**

- Providing an `APP_BASE_HREF` DI token inside the `AppModule`
  providers that would use the `LOCALE_ID` as its value and removing
  the `baseHref` settings from the `angular.json` configuration. This
  works "somewhat" in that I am redirected from `localhost:8000` to
  e.g. `localhost:8000/fr/`, but it also results in undesired redirects
  because I assume the route lookup logic happens before the base href
  token is injected and thus it cannot recognize the URL and redirects
  to the default route.
- Providing a `deployUrl` value inside the `angular.json` configuration, to no avail.

**Similar issues**

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14925 is basically the exact same issue. Unfortunately, all such issues have been closed without providing an actual solution on how to restore the old behaviour.

Comment: I see the discussion on this at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16179 -- does this imply that a deployment to prod will always and only have a base-href of "/"?

Comment: @eflat I'm afraid the question is a bit too generic - it would depend on your Angular CLI settings as well as your web server settings. But in my case: No, it will still have the base-href you specified in `angular.json`.

Comment: We did get our issue sorted by comparing against a new 'ng new' project. The baseUrl in tsconfig.json had been changed and we had trouble isolating that as the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I learned through https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16179, it was in fact the old behaviour that should have not been possible in the first place.

When running the app locally, you can only run one language at a time. Assuming that the app is German by default, running it would serve it at localhost:8000. When running the English version, the app would be served at localhost:8000/en. That's true for both Angular CLI 7 and 8. What changed with version 8 is simply that it will not redirect you automatically to localhost:8000/en when running the English version and navigating to localhost:8000. So for us it meant that we slightly had to adjust our dev workflow (simply by making sure we open the app at the correct address), nothing actually changed on our production environment because there all languages are live.